# Tag Completion in Search Bar

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, search, autocomplete

When typing a tag in the *search bar* it would be sweet like a thousand unicorns if it would suggest tags as you type. It could detect when to show suggestions based on the `[` character.

For bonus points they could be styled just like the Tags field on the Ask Question page.

Comment: +1, was about to post this exact request.

Comment: I just noticed (on [productivity.se]) that this happens if you only type a tag: If you type *procrastionation* it changes to *[procrastination]*. Likewise e.g. on [SO]: type *Delphi* and it becomes *[Delphi]*

Comment: @JanDoggen - Huh. If it did that in 2014, it doesn't seem to now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because Delphi is less popular these days. Try with C#, JavaScript, etc, and it will become a tag. If the search term is exact match of one of the top 50 tags on the site, it will auto convert.

Comment: @Shadow9 - Doesn't for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg7Xt.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/66L1K.png I also tried an opening `[`. Not seeing anything automatic.

Comment: @Shadow9 - **Ah**, if you **only** type something that matches a tag (from some list, apparently), it works. But not if you type anything in addition to the tag. (And, as you say, only with certain things, which no longer include [tag:delphi] apparently. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that's true. It's very limited, but still useful. :)

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, yes, a thousand times yes

It should work just like tagging a question, but perhaps be triggered by having a leading `[` (whereas when tagging a question, it's a dedicated field so you don't need the `[`):

[image]

This could cut down on duplicate questions, and just generally make search better. I just searched for `[react-js] error handling` and didn't find anything — because the tag is `[reactjs]`, not `[react-js]`.