# Tag autocompletion in search textbox

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag Completion in Search Bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107094/tag-completion-in-search-bar)

It'd be super-useful if when I typed *[*  + some characters when using the search box, all matching tags displayed just like when one posts a question.

Comment: You do realise that there are more than 1400 meta tags? On a main site rather than a meta there's going to be a **lot** more as well (synonyms notwithstanding).

Comment: @tombull89: I don't understand your objection. Are you concerned about usability, performance or server load? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm not terribly concerned, no. I guess that the tag would autocomplete for the most (10, 20?) popular tags to start with rather than displaying all 1000-odd tags.

Comment: @Mat my bad for not performing a search - I'm sorry.

Comment: I reckon that completion could be triggered only after introducing a certain amount of characters...